# How to use ffmpeg to mix two audio files to a single one?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mixing

I want to mix two audio files to a single one use ffmpeg. So I download the latest version of ffmpeg, and check the document and get the code:

```
ffmpeg -i 10001.wav -i 201.wav -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest output.wav
```

but I got this error:

```
ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  9 2012 16:22:59 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/ --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
  libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
  libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
  libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[wav @ 0x13d08100] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5120000
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from '10001.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:07.91, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_alaw ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
[wav @ 0x13d08980] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5120000
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from '201.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:11.88, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
[abuffersink @ 0x13d268c0] No opaque field provided, an AVABufferSinkParams struct is required
```

Can anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: You have two mono input files. Do you want to merge them into a mono output, or create a multi-channel output? Can you provide the input files?